# Titanium build error: app is a Appcelerator Platform registered application

Tags: javascript, titanium-sdk

I am getting this error

```
[ERROR]TiTanium_prep failed to run (10)

[ERROR]This application cannot be built with the Titanium open source SDK because it is an Appcelerator Platform registered application. Please use the Appcelerator Platform CLI tools or Appcelerator Studio to build this application.

Build failed. Process exited with code 1.
```

Titanium version 11.1.1 GA

Answer (score 0):

The error is `because it is an Appcelerator Platform registered application`

Please check this tutorial: https://fromzerotoapp.com/transfer-your-app-from-appc-cli-to-ti-cli/

Basically you have an old GUID in your app. Create a new one and add that to the `<guid>` field.